# WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver() is this compile-time or runtime binding?

Tags: java, selenium

It looks like I got a bit confused in my core Java concepts .Please have a look below .

```
    class A{
       public void func1()
       {
           System.out.println("Hello A");
       }
    }
    class B extends A{
       public void func1(){
           System.out.println("Hello B");
       }
     }
   class C {
        public static void main( String args[]) {

           A myobj = new B();
           myobj.func1();
       }
}
```

As we know Webdriver is an interface & FirefoxDriver is the implementing class for Webdriver , so based on the above example is it right to assume that the statement : `WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver()`  is an example of late binding.

Comment: *"Since the exact type of the object is unknown at compile time..."* What makes you think that? What else could either `A` or `B` be within `main`?

Comment: "Late binding" is when the method to call is looked up at runtime, so technically your code fragment doesn't demonstrate it because it doesn't call any methods

Comment: Made some changes to the code fragment.B extends A and overrides its func1() method and when we call func1() method from a reference variable of type A, it doesn't call func1() method from A class instead it calls func1() method from B subclass because object referenced by A type is a B object. This resolution happens only at runtime because object only created during runtime .

Comment: @Bohemian: `myobj.func1()` is calling a method.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I meant the fragment the question is about (in title and last "punch" line): `WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver()`. Constructors a statically bound. at compile time.
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver()` is this compile-time or runtime binding?

That's compile-time binding to the class called `FirefoxDriver`. It will use whatever `FirefoxDriver` class is in the classpath. This is just about as compile-time as Java gets, as Java works from the classpath at compile-time and also at runtime.

Here's an example of *runtime* binding:

```
String driverName = /*...get the name from somewhere, like a properties file...*/;
WebDriver driver = Class.forName(driverName).newInstance();
```